# Why doesn't UITableViewController rotate?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to have my UITableViewController to be landscape orientation only, but it won't even rotate from portrait...
I set orientation properties to landscape in my Project Settings, and I changed orientation of UITableViewController in  StoryBoards, but still nothing. What also I should do ?
Running on device / simulator it's locked on Portrait Left.

http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/9652/tavblef.png

Comment: In your view controller, there should be a method `-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate`, if that is returning `NO` or `FALSE`, that might be the issue.

Comment: what ios version do you use?

Comment: @Mike D: It's new project and shouldAutoRotate has default value - YES

Comment: It might be calling this method then: `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`. ([Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-AppendixA)) It will be listed under "Deprecated in iOS 6.0."

Comment: Also, if you select the target, then the summary tab, you should the supported interafce orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have to set this four orientation support in your "Project name" -> "Target" -> "Info":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this is in your viewcontroller.m file

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight|| interfaceOrientation==     UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is quite simple. 
I created a new project, and a new UITableViewController in Storyboards, but was I working on default UIViewController class, instead of creating subclass of UITableViewController...